# How can I use ParallaxBackground in AndEngine?

Tags: android, opengl-es2, andengine

I'm new to game development with  AndEngine. I want to add ParallaxBackground but I don't know how to change the background when the player moves. I'm using arrows for moving a player.

Now my question is where I write the code `parallaxBackground.setParallaxValue(5);`?

I have written this line in `onAreaTouched` method of arrow but it does not work.

**Code**

```
private Camera mCamera;
private static  int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
private static  int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

private BitmapTextureAtlas bgTexture;
private ITextureRegion bgTextureRegion;

@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {

    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    bgTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(),2160,480,TextureOptions.REPEATING_BILINEAR);
    bgTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(bgTexture, this, "background.png", 0, 0);
    bgTexture.load(); 
}
@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {

    this.getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    Scene scene = new Scene();
    scene.setBackground(new Background(Color.BLACK));

    final ParallaxBackground parallaxBackground = new ParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0);
    final VertexBufferObjectManager vertexBufferObjectManager = this.getVertexBufferObjectManager();

    parallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.bgTextureRegion.getHeight(), this.bgTextureRegion, vertexBufferObjectManager)));
    scene.setBackground(parallaxBackground);

Robot robot = new Robot();

    // add Player
    final AnimatedSprite animatedRobotSprite = new AnimatedSprite(robot.centerX, robot.centerY, 122, 126, (ITiledTextureRegion) robotTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    scene.attachChild(animatedRobotSprite);
    animatedRobotSprite.animate(new long[]{1250,50,50});


    // add right arrow button
    Sprite rightArrowSprite = new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT-70, rightArrowTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager()){

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

            switch (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {

            case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                moveRight = true;
                parallaxBackground.setParallaxValue(5);
                break;

            case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                moveRight = true;
                break;

            case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
                moveRight = false;
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
        }
    };
    scene.attachChild(rightArrowSprite);

    scene.registerTouchArea(rightArrowSprite);

    scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);

    scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionMoveEnabled(true);

    scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

        @Override
        public void reset() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

            if ( moveRight ){
                animatedRobotSprite.setPosition(animatedRobotSprite.getX()+speedX, animatedRobotSprite.getY());


            }
        }
    });

    return scene;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Parallax layers themselves can be quite a bit of trouble- especially if you want them to move with the character rather than just being static or moving at a constant rate of speed.

My suggestion: One AndEngine user uploaded a custom ParallaxLayer if you're in the GLES2.0 branch that can be found [here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/features/parallaxlayer-t5390.html#p23966), I'd recommend using it as it supports scrolling at variable rates and overall seems like more of what you're looking for.  Good luck with AndEngine- it's a fun way to make an Android game!